# Why does the C23 standard decrease the max size of an object the implementation must support?

Tags: c, standards, c23

I'm currently reading the new draft of the C23 standard ([N3088](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n3088.pdf)), and I've noticed that in §5.2.4.1 the standard states:

> The implementation shall be able to translate and execute a program that uses but does not exceed
> the following limitations for these constructs and entities: ... 32767 bytes in an object (in a hosted environment only)

This was the number in ANSI C/C89, and since C99 it was raised to 65535 - what is the reason to lower it back to the original amount?

I tried to look for any reference to it here and in the [WG 14 Document Log](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/wg14_document_log) but didn't find anything.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The change was reverted so that `ptrdiff_t`, which has to be signed, can be only 16bit wide, while still representing the byte difference between the beginning and end of all objects in an implementation, especially embedded ones. With these requirements objects in the implementation mustn't be larger than 32767 bytes.

See the proposal [N2808](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2808.htm) and also C/C++ compatibility discussion in [N2883](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2883.pdf).

Comment: That explains it. Interesting choice to cancel a previous change.
Thanks for the answer and the links!